# How can I install NodeJS-lts on my Android 5 phone with termux?

Tags: android, node.js, termux

I have an old phone that runs with Android 5 and I want to host Discord bots with this phone like vds. But the repositories of Termux for Android 5 only includes Nodejs v13. So, I get “cannot find module ‘note:events’” warning when I run the bots. I know the solution for upgrading Nodejs version, but I can’t find any proper repository. In fact, I don’t even know Android 5 can run v13 external version. How can I make this project work?